# Access to Protected methods in Angular Class

Tags: angular, amcharts

Is there a way to get access to protected properties of an Angular Library Class from an Angular app?

For example, I need to get the value that is in a protected property **_gridInterval** from the [Class "DateAxes" of the library amChart4](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/master/src/.internal/charts/axes/DateAxis.ts)

But, things like:

```
dateAxis._gridInterval
```

Give me the error message:

> error TS2445: Property '_gridInterval' is protected and only
>   accessible within class 'DateAxis' and its subclasses.

I know that it is not a Good Practice (try to access to protected values) but I need to get that value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s probably not such a good idea, but if you must do it, you could try something like this:

```js
dateAxis['_gridInterval']
```

This might also work:

```
const da: any = dateAxis;
da._gridInterval
```

Comment: thank, dateAxis['_gridInterval'].timeUnit work right. I know that It was not the best, but I need to get that value ...